Duplication of schedular running in two replica set in java springboot
I have two replica set of my service running on kubernetes environment. Issue that i am facing is that I have a schedular that will run on 1am and it will send some notification. but when both replicas are running it sends duplicate notifications to users.
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * *")
public void agentExpirationAlertForAGENT_ALERT_1() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ConfigurationModel config = configRepository.findByConfigKey(ConfigurationTYpe.AGENT_ALERT_1);
    List<ReceivingCountryAgent> receivingCountryAgents = receivingCountryAgentRepository.findAllByAgentStatusAndStatus(
            ReceivingCountryAgent.AgentStatus.APPROVED,
            ReceivingCountryAgent.EnableDisableStatus.ACTIVE
    );

    String json = config.getConfigJson();


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);

    int days = node.get("noOfDays").asInt();


    // Process alerts for all agents for 30-day notification
    receivingCountryAgents.forEach(receivingCountryAgent -> {
        Optional<ReceivingCountryAgentDocument> optionalLicenceDoc = receivingCountryAgent.getDocuments().stream()
                .filter(doc -> doc.getType().equals(ReceivingCountryAgentDocument.DocumentType.AGREEMENT))
                .findFirst();
        String message = node.get("emailMessage").asText();

        message = message.replace("${name}", receivingCountryAgent.getAgentName());
        message = message.replace("${days}", String.valueOf(days));

        String finalMessage = message;
        optionalLicenceDoc.ifPresent(licenceDoc -> {
            Date expiryDate = licenceDoc.getExpiryDate();
            if (expiryDate != null) {
                // Send a notification if expiring in 30 days
                sendNotificationIfExpiring(receivingCountryAgent, expiryDate, days, finalMessage, ConfigurationTYpe.AGENT_ALERT_1);
            }
        });
    });
}


Does Run Scheduled Cron method in Spring from single pod if multiple pods exist on Kubernetes have an answer for you?  The answers there are a little light on details but they do describe a couple of approaches to this.

Seems like a job for quartz with persistent store.

DOn't use @Scheduled if you need a single instance to run. Use something like Quartz or JobRunR for that.
